# Errors while calling a custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a custom widget which is called ListerCommande(), and I'am trying to call it in homeActivity but it gives me errors ,I tried to use Expanded and adding mainAxisSize but I still have the same errors could someone help me, this is where I called the widget :

```
body: new Container(
          child:
          SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
          ListerCommande()
                            ],
                        )
                       ),
               )
```

ListerCommande widget :

```
class ListerCommande extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Les Commandes"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildCommandeList(context)
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
  StreamBuilder<List<CommandeWithClientWithClientTypeWithCarteSimWithDemandeCarte>> _buildCommandeList(BuildContext context) {
    final dao = Provider.of<CommandeDao>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: dao.watchAllCommandes(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<CommandeWithClientWithClientTypeWithCarteSimWithDemandeCarte>> snapshot) {
        final commandes = snapshot.data ?? List();
        return ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: commandes.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            final itemCommande = commandes[index];
            return _buildListItem(itemCommande, dao,context);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
  Widget _buildListItem(CommandeWithClientWithClientTypeWithCarteSimWithDemandeCarte itemCommande, CommandeDao dao,BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
      secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        new IconSlideAction(
            caption: 'Delete',
            color: Colors.red,
            icon: Icons.delete,
            onTap: () {
              dao.deleteCommande(itemCommande.commande);
              dao.deleteClient(itemCommande.client);
              dao.deleteTypeClient(itemCommande.typeClient);

            }
        )

      ],
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text("Commande Numero : " + itemCommande.commande.idCommande.toString()),

        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage(itemCommande)),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the errors that gave me

```
I/flutter (32394): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (32394): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (32394): FlutterError contained multiple error summaries.
I/flutter (32394): All FlutterError objects should have only a single short (one line) summary description of the
I/flutter (32394): problem that was detected.
I/flutter (32394): Malformed FlutterError:
I/flutter (32394):   RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (32394):   This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter (32394):   inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter (32394):   RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (32394):   This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter (32394):   inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter (32394):   The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#e3a3d relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter (32394):     needs compositing
I/flutter (32394):     creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#c2421] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter (32394):       _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#a3e7d] ←
I/flutter (32394):       Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#ef06e] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ←
I/flutter (32394):       RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
I/flutter (32394):     parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (32394):     constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=560.0)
I/flutter (32394):     size: MISSING
I/flutter (32394):   The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:
I/flutter (32394):     BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (32394):   The exact size it was given was:
I/flutter (32394):     Size(360.0, Infinity)
I/flutter (32394):   See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.
I/flutter (32394): 
I/flutter (32394): The malformed error has 2 summaries.
I/flutter (32394): Summary 1: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (32394): Summary 2: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (32394): 
I/flutter (32394): This error should still help you solve your problem, however please also report this malformed error
I/flutter (32394): in the framework by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (32394):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (32394): 
I/flutter (32394): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (32394): #0      new FlutterError.fromParts.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart:540:9)
I/flutter (32394): #1      new FlutterError.fromParts (package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart:543:6)
I/flutter (32394): #2      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1966:28)
I/flutter (32394): #3      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2029:6)
I/flutter (32394): #4      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1740:7)
I/flutter (32394): #5      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1742:6)
I/flutter (32394): #6      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:355:5)
I/flutter (32394): #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #8      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #10     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #11     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1214:11)
I/flutter (32394): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #13     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:743:15)
I/flutter (32394): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #15     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:497:13)
I/flutter (32394): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #31     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #33     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #35     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (32394): #36     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:443:7)
I/flutter (32394): #37     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (32394): #38     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (32394): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #40     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #42     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #43     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1214:11)
I/flutter (32394): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #45     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #47     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #49     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #51     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #53     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #55     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #57     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #59     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #60     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3076:13)
I/flutter (32394): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #62     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter (32394): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #64     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #66     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #68     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #70     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #72     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #74     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #76     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #78     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #80     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #82     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #83     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #84     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #86     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #88     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #90     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #91     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3076:13)
I/flutter (32394): #92     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): moor: SELECT commandes.id_commande AS "commandes.id_commande", commandes.clientid AS "commandes.clientid", commandes.date AS "commandes.date", clients.id_client AS "clients.id_client", clients.type_clientid AS "clients.type_clientid", clients.nom AS "clients.nom", clients.prenom AS "clients.prenom", clients.ddn AS "clients.ddn", clients.ville AS "clients.ville", clients.ncd AS "clients.ncd", clients.image_devant AS "clients.image_devant", clients.image_arriere AS "clients.image_arriere", type_clients.id_type_client AS "type_clients.id_type_client", type_clients.prix_e AS "type_clients.prix_e", type_clients.prix_p AS "type_clients.prix_p", type_clients.libelle AS "type_clients.libelle", demande_cartes.numero_demande AS "demande_cartes.numero_demande", demande_cartes.id_commande AS "demande_cartes.id_commande", demande_cartes.carte_sim_id AS "demande_cartes.carte_sim_id", carte_sims.id_carte_sim AS "carte_sims.id_carte_sim", carte_sims.code_bare1 AS "carte_sims.code_bare1", carte_sims.code_bare2 AS "carte_sims
I/flutter (32394): #93     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter (32394): #94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #95     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #97     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #98     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #99     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #101    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #103    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #105    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (32394): #106    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:7)
I/flutter (32394): #107    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:151:13)
I/flutter (32394): #108    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1496:7)
I/flutter (32394): #109    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:765:18)
I/flutter (32394): #110    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:346:19)
I/flutter (32394): #111    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter (32394): #112    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
I/flutter (32394): #113    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1016:15)
I/flutter (32394): #114    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:958:9)
I/flutter (32394): #115    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter (32394): #124    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (32394): #125    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (32394): #126    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter (32394): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (32394): 
I/flutter (32394): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#37a5d relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter (32394):   creator: CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter (32394):     _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#17d48 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ←
I/flutter (32394):     PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← Material ← PrimaryScrollController ← _ScaffoldScope ←
I/flutter (32394):     Scaffold ← ⋯
I/flutter (32394):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (32394):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (32394):   size: Size(360.0, Infinity)
I/flutter (32394): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter (32394):     child 1: RenderRepaintBoundary#26867 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):       child: RenderCustomPaint#17704 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):         child: RenderRepaintBoundary#b892c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):           child: _RenderScrollSemantics#97627 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):             child: RenderPointerListener#9c994 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):     child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#de378 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):       child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#a5284 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):         child: RenderAnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>#93e71 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):           child: RenderPhysicalModel#5f624 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):             child: _RenderInkFeatures#eda43 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):     child 3: RenderStack#b4a86 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):       child 1: RenderTransform#808c4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (32394):         child: RenderTransform#52fae NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (32394): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (32394): Another exception was thrown: FlutterError contained multiple error summaries.
I/flutter (32394): Another exception was thrown: FlutterError contained multiple error summaries.
I/flutter (32394): Another exception was thrown: FlutterError contained multiple error summaries.
I/flutter (32394): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '>' was called on null.
```

Comment: Saw nothing wrong with your code, show us the code of ListerCommande Widget please

Comment: @RodrigoBastos I added it

Comment: @RodrigoBastos I think I found the problem but I have a question if you don't mind , while creating a widget we shouldn't use material widget like scaffold ?

Comment: You will be using material widgets most of the time. Unless you are programming for ios and want ios style widgets than you will use cupertino widgets. Right now flutter has much more material widgets than cupertino ones

Comment: When calling ListerCommande() in the body, place it in an Expanded widget. Like so: `Expanded(child: ListerCommande())`

Answer (score 3):

ListerCommande() is a list view which is overflowing its bounce and causing that error. Place it in an Expanded.

```
body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                   Expanded(child: ListerCommande()),
                ],
             )
          ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Column(
    children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
          child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: HorizontalBarLabelChart.withSampleData(),
              )),
        ),

      Expanded(
          child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: DateTimeComboLinePointChart.withSampleData(),
                ),
              )),
        ),

    ],
  ),
```

example is not your's but you can use this approach here is the result of this

[image]